# How to change color in ExpandableRecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, expandablerecyclerview

I am using this [library](https://github.com/ayalma/ExpandableRecyclerView) but I can't get to a way to change the group background color from white.

[image: MainActivity]

### EDIT: the xml files as requested in comments:

> content_main.xml

the content_main file which include the expandable recyclerview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ayalma.ir.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> activity_main.xml

the main activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#64dd17"
    tools:context="ayalma.ir.sample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> row_drawer.xml

the custom row layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffb74d">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/carbon_toolbarHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/carbon_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/carbon_padding" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post code with xml file

Comment: change backgound color  in exr_group.xml

Comment: change this color #ffb74d

Comment: tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group" open exr_group.xml and change color

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar xml files added

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan this color is for the row items I want to change the background of "group:1 from white

Comment: @akhilesh0707 can you explain in more detail?
there is no exr_group.xml in my layout folder

Comment: add this line to your tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group" <ayalma.ir.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerView and change color

Comment: @akhilesh0707 thank you 
If you want to post it as answer 
and if can I ask how did it work ?

Comment: I have checked library which link you provided above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your previous library from Gradle

```
compile 'com.github.ayalma:ExpandableRecyclerView:0.2.0'
```

Add this library to your Gradle

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

Copy this file to your package

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

public class ExpandableRecyclerView extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView {
    public ExpandableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        initRecycler();
    }

    public ExpandableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initRecycler();
    }

    public ExpandableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initRecycler();
    }

    private void initRecycler() {
        setClipToPadding(false);
        setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        //begin boilerplate code that allows parent classes to save state
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        //end

        if (getAdapter() != null)
            ss.stateToSave = ((Adapter) this.getAdapter()).getExpandedGroups();

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        //begin boilerplate code so parent classes can restore state
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState))  // if state is not instance of out SaveState just restore in reg way
        {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        // else if cast him to SavedState

        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        //end

        if (getAdapter() != null)
            ((Adapter) getAdapter()).setExpandedGroups(ss.stateToSave);
    }

    static class SavedState implements Parcelable {
        public static final SavedState EMPTY_STATE = new SavedState() {
        };

        SparseBooleanArray stateToSave;
        Parcelable superState;

        SavedState() {
            superState = null;
        }

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            this.superState = superState != EMPTY_STATE ? superState : null;
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            Parcelable superState = in.readParcelable(ExpandableRecyclerView.class.getClassLoader());
            this.superState = superState != null ? superState : EMPTY_STATE;
            this.stateToSave = in.readSparseBooleanArray();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel out, int flags) {
            out.writeParcelable(superState, flags);
            out.writeSparseBooleanArray(this.stateToSave);
        }

        public Parcelable getSuperState() {
            return superState;
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Creator<SavedState>() {
                    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SavedState(in);
                    }

                    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }


    @Override
    public void setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        if (!(adapter instanceof Adapter))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adapter has to be of type ExpandableRecyclerView.Adapter");
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public static abstract class Adapter<CVH extends ViewHolder, GVH extends ViewHolder, C, G> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        private OnChildItemClickedListener onChildItemClickedListener;

        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;

        SparseBooleanArray expanded = new SparseBooleanArray();

        public Adapter() {
        }

        boolean isExpanded(int group) {
            return expanded.get(group);
        }

        SparseBooleanArray getExpandedGroups() {
            return expanded;
        }

        public void setExpandedGroups(SparseBooleanArray expanded) {
            this.expanded = expanded;
        }

        public void expand(int group) {
            if (isExpanded(group))
                return;

            // this lines of code calculate number of shown item in recycler view. also group is counting .
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < group; i++) {
                position++;
                if (isExpanded(i))
                    position += getChildItemCount(i);
            }
            position++; // this for percent group

            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, getChildItemCount(group)); // notify recycler view for expanding
            expanded.put(group, true); // save expanding in sparce array
        }

        public void collapse(int group) {
            if (!isExpanded(group)) // if is not expanded . so nothing to collapse.
                return;

            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < group; i++) {
                position++;
                if (isExpanded(i))
                    position += getChildItemCount(i); // item
            }
            position++;
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, getChildItemCount(group));
            expanded.put(group, false);
        }

        public abstract int getGroupItemCount();

        public abstract int getChildItemCount(int group);

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= getGroupItemCount(); i++) {
                count += isExpanded(i) ? getChildItemCount(i) + 1 : 1;
            }
            return count;
        }

        public abstract G getGroupItem(int position);

        public abstract C getChildItem(int group, int position);

        public Object getItem(int i) {
            int group = 0;
            while (group <= getGroupItemCount()) {
                if (i > 0 && !isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i > 0 && isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    if (i < getChildItemCount(group))
                        return getChildItem(group, i);
                    i -= getChildItemCount(group);
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 0)
                    return getGroupItem(group);
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
            int group = 0;
            while (group <= getGroupItemCount()) {
                if (i > 0 && !isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i > 0 && isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    if (i < getChildItemCount(group)) {
                        onBindChildViewHolder((CVH) holder, group, i);
                        return;
                    }
                    i -= getChildItemCount(group);
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    onBindGroupViewHolder((GVH) holder, group);
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return viewType == TYPE_HEADER ? onCreateGroupViewHolder(parent) : onCreateChildViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        }

        protected abstract GVH onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

        protected abstract CVH onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

        public abstract int getChildItemViewType(int group, int position);

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int i) {
            int group = 0;
            while (group <= getGroupItemCount()) {
                if (i > 0 && !isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i > 0 && isExpanded(group)) {
                    i--;
                    if (i < getChildItemCount(group))
                        return getChildItemViewType(group, i);
                    i -= getChildItemCount(group);
                    group++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 0)
                    return TYPE_HEADER;
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        public void setOnChildItemClickedListener(OnChildItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener) {
            this.onChildItemClickedListener = onItemClickedListener;
        }

        public void onBindChildViewHolder(CVH holder, final int group, final int position) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Adapter.this.onChildItemClickedListener != null) {
                        Adapter.this.onChildItemClickedListener.onChildItemClicked(group, position);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        public void onBindGroupViewHolder(final GVH holder, final int group) {
            if (holder instanceof GroupViewHolder)
                ((GroupViewHolder) holder).setExpanded(isExpanded(group));

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isExpanded(group)) {
                        collapse(group);
                        if (holder instanceof GroupViewHolder)
                            ((GroupViewHolder) holder).collapse();
                    } else {
                        expand(group);
                        if (holder instanceof GroupViewHolder)
                            ((GroupViewHolder) holder).expand();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static abstract class GroupViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public GroupViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        public abstract void expand();

        public abstract void collapse();

        public abstract void setExpanded(boolean expanded);

        public abstract boolean isExpanded();
    }

    public static class SimpleGroupViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {
        ImageView expandedIndicator;
        TextView text;
        private boolean expanded;

        public SimpleGroupViewHolder(Context context) {
            super(View.inflate(context, R.layout.exr_group, null));

            itemView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            expandedIndicator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carbon_groupExpandedIndicator);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carbon_groupText);
        }

        public void expand() {
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(200);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    ViewHelper.setRotation(expandedIndicator, 180 * (float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                    expandedIndicator.postInvalidate();
                }
            });
            animator.start();
            expanded = true;
        }

        public void collapse() {
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);
            animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(200);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    ViewHelper.setRotation(expandedIndicator, 180 * (float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                    expandedIndicator.postInvalidate();
                }
            });
            animator.start();
            expanded = false;
        }

        public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
            ViewHelper.setRotation(expandedIndicator, expanded ? 180 : 0);
            this.expanded = expanded;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isExpanded() {
            return expanded;
        }

        public void setText(String t) {
            text.setText(t);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    public interface OnChildItemClickedListener {
        void onChildItemClicked(int group, int position);
    }

}
```

group xml copy to layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fefefe"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carbon_groupText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/carbon_groupExpandedIndicator"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:tint="#000000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_more_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

copy inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M16.59,8.59L12,13.17 7.41,8.59 6,10l6,6 6,-6z"/>
</vector>
```

Now user this inside your xml

```
<com.example.package.ExpandableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

instead of

```
 <ayalma.ir.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your

```
<ayalma.ir.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerView
tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group"
```

And change backgound color

Comment: can you give more detail on how 
tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group" 
works

Comment: Check the library you will see tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group" line inside <ayalma.ir.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerView which is default group header xml

Comment: ok i got that but where exr_group does it affect by gradle build?

Comment: I made new layout and changed  tools:listitem="@layout/exr_group"  to my new layout but it didn't take effect what am I missing?

Comment: did you change your layout on tools:listitem="@layout/custom_layout"

Comment: open ExpandableRecyclerView and goto GroupViewHolder and change ur xml to super(View.inflate(context, R.layout.exr_group, null)); at line 382

Comment: I changed it but I can't edit it in ExpandableRecyclerView.SimpleGroupViewHolder I can just view it

Comment: copy ExpandableRecyclerView inside your project and use through your project

Comment: is this the only way ?

Comment: @Zacktamondo check my other answer